# Gmail REST Api to send Google Wallet money request

Tags: rest, gmail, android-pay

Wondering if anyone has tried using the Gmail Rest API to construct an email requesting funds via google wallet (attach money)?

Line of thinking: In the gmail app you can click that $ icon and insert a request for funds, is this also possible via the API?